# How to delete a file before build abort in a critical section with ANT?

Tags: jenkins, ant, continuous-integration, abort, critical-section

Hy guys!

I would like to delete a file if my build abort.

This is my critical section :

```
<touch file="PATH/lockfile.txt" />
<unzip src="PATH/archive.zip" dest="PATH/toto"/>
```

So, if the build abort during `<unzip>` i want to delete `lockfile.txt`
How can I do this?

Don't hesitate to ask for more details
Thanks a lot :) !

Comment: Are you using any libraries such as `ant-contrib`?

Comment: Yes ! I can't use another libraries...

Comment: What is the general case when unzip fails in your case? Did you say `yes` to tell that you using other libs? It was confusing reply.

Comment: Sorry, I can't use other libs...

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking on the job's level - add a post build operation to remove this file. that way builds that are aborted (due timeout or other reason) finishes immediately the build section and moving to the post build. This will ensure the deletion of the file under the same session\workspace.

1. Go to Post-build Actions and add [Execute a set of scripts](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PostBuildScript+Plugin)
2. add a build step -> Execute Apache Ant
3. Make sure you have ANT installed on the machine or configured in Jenkins management as an automatic installation
4. Run the following ANT script:

`<property environment="env"/>
 <property name="ws" value="${env.WORKSPACE}"/>
 <delete file="${ws}\${file_Name}"/>`

Good luck!

Comment: I hope do that, but I have other jobs in progress and if I don't delete this file, they cannot run... this file is created to say "hey guys, when I delete it you can run..."

Comment: I personally don't like I\O flags in order to run\not run something - I think it's a bad practice. can't you manage the jobs to trigger separately? using Throttle concurrent builds, lock plugin or any other method to manage it on the build pipeline level and not the process level?

Comment: I'm student and I work in a company that has been using this system since a very long time...  I can't manage the jobs as I wish :/

Comment: Either way my answer stays the same - add a post build operation to your jobs to delete the file. you want me to edit the answer with ANT code to do so (will be agnostic to the OS)?

Comment: Yes with pleasure!